# Design pattern for wrapping aws-sdk Javascript v3

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, design-patterns, aws-sdk-js

Our team is moving from aws-sdk v2 to v3. We have a common package that has a wrapper around aws-sdk which takes care of common logging to aws sdk service calls and update few configs ( This wrapper is not per client)

To elaborate it further, we define and import dependencies like this

- in v2:
  `"@aws-sdk": "^2.xxx"`
- in v3: it's module per client.
  `@aws-sdk/client-lambda":"^3.xxx`

With the migration to v3. Which has per client module imports. I'm rewriting the wrapper.

I am wondering what is the best design pattern for doing a job like this? I am have been looking at the factory design pattern, but not sure if this is the correct one.

Comment: Hi. Maybe I'm not understanding your question but if you have a wrapper, why do you also have per client module imports of the underlying aws sdk? Whats the point of the wrapper if client code needs to import the wrapper and add an import statement for the s3 sdk?

Comment: @usman The point of the wrapper is to remove the code duplication. I want to be able to put some common loggers and middleware stack while calling aws SDK for every client. The main challenge for me is the wrapper will also return the only necessary imports from the aws-sdk/client-*.

Comment: So in each user of the wrapper the import needs to go from being generic "@aws-sdk" to more specific"@aws-sdk/aws-service":"version"...If thats correct since you mentioned factory pattern I'm guessing you're trying to make "aws-service" a parameter that the caller specifies and the "@aws-sdk" and version part are taken care of inside the wrapper correct?

Comment: @Usman Mutawakil, Yea that's exactly how I'm visualizing, my main intention is to add common loggers, retry strategy  and emit metrics basing up on the error to all the aws-sdk client calls. Looking for a good design to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Given the requirements you specified I don't see anything wrong with a factory and since it's mandatory for V3 that you specify the service, I can't see how else you would do it other than to make the service info inputs to a factory of some sort. Especially if you're going to be using a wrapper anyway, moving the service import details from the import statement to the factory seems like you're not adding any additional code. I know you were probably looking for a more explicit pattern but I think what you're doing is correct given what you've outlined.